# Send iPhone Users A Daily Quote

Tags: iphone, wordpress, ios4

I have a daily quote that I post on my wordpress blog each and every day. I want to make an iOS app for my subscribers so that they can get the daily quote on their mobile devices and also be able to save their favorites, etc.

Originally, my plan was to use the RSS feed of the wordpress blog. However, I don't really like the way this would work. I would rather be able to send the quote directly from my computer (or iPhone) and have it be "pushed" to my users. Right now my blog has over 450 posts. I want my users to have access to all past posts, and it seems like a slow way of going to have my RSS feed set to show that many posts.

I don't have any experience in this sort of thing. All my developer experience is in game dev and I could really use some help figuring this out. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a sample project for getting and reading and RSS feed. That would be a good place to start. Once you understand the basics of iOS programming and design, then you could considering using the APNS (Apple Push Notification Services). That feature (fairly complex) allows you to push your quote on screen. But if you quote is too long, that might not make any sense.

But your first step is to get your feet wet and get up to speed with iOS development. Give yourself a few weeks for that at least.

Comment: I actually have a year and a half of iPhone programming experience. Unfortunately, I have only worked on games, and none of the projects I have worked on have ever brought me into contact with the internet side of things. I really need someone to point me in the right direction as to how to get my foot in the door with the online side of things.